# How to build debug/release image by rpm build?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm using rpm build(rpmbuild -ba rpm-spec) to build image. I want to build two image, one is build with gcc -O0 option, one is to build with gcc -O2 option.

I don't know if there is debug option in rpm command line to switch build process, or some option in rpm spec.

If there is, I could use one build.sh and one spec file to build two image. If no, I could only use two build.sh and two spec files.

So how to deal with this? Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Use the conditional builds. See: http://rpm.org/user_doc/conditional_builds.html